# How can I sort a php associative array according to another array with the same key value

Tags: php, arrays, usort

To make my question easier to understand, I will give an example output.

var_dump output:

Array 1:

array(22) { ["#HIDDEN_ID"]=> string(10) "08/11/2013"

Array 2:

array(22) { ["#HIDDEN_ID"]=> string(96) "www.google.co.uk....."

Array one is sorted by most recent date, however my second array is not but it has the same file ids.

Therefore I would like to sort my second array to how my first arrays file ids are stored.

I have no clue how to do this using uasort or usort.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
$keys = array_keys($array1);

array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $array2);
```

Comment: Actually, while testing this it did not work. As Before I didnt have the same size arrays, now I do and it doesnt sort them